# set data source for both spring JPA and hibernate persistence API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Spring and hibernate. I am struggling to do my job with fast self learning but without luck. I would be very grateful for your patience and help.

My project involves data collecting(collect data and put it into database) and presenting(json REST-ful api).
My plan is to persist collected data with hibernate persistence API:

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(this);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

For this to work, I have to write a `persistence.xml` to specify the data source.

For presentation part, I have to specify data source in spring's `application.properties` file.

Can I specify data source in just one place for this use case? For example, maybe I can use persistence.xml for all at once.

And preferably, I'd like to put data source outside of the jar file.

**EDIT:**
I end up with a single application.properties file, which defines both hibernate data settings and spring hibernate database settings:

```
spring.datasource.name=gateway
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/gateway
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=123456
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/gateway
```

Comment: *For this to work, I have to write a persistence.xml to specify the data source*: no, you don't. Read the spring documentation.

Comment: "spring JPA" simply uses a valid JPA provider. It doesn't use anything itself!

Comment: Since you have `application.properties`, are you using Spring Boot? Because you should have this file if you are using Spring Boot...

Comment: I sympathise but you might get down-voted for this question. You really will get more benefit doing a Spring Udemy course or Youtube tutorials or something than posting questions like this one here. Need to learn fundementals first.